# iOS - reference to caller viewController

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, ipad

I am in a viewController, lets call it vcA and I call a second one vcB, using

```
[self presentModalViewController:vcB animated:YES];
```

once vcB is loaded is there any way to obtain a reference to vcA?

Yes, I know that I can subclass vcB and add a property to it. I am just asking if there is some native iOS method/property/whatever that already does that.

I am on a navigationController app.

Thanks.

Comment: In **which** view controller are you in? B or A?

Comment: I am in B wanting a reference to A.

Comment: Its a better idea to use a delegate here, the presentModalViewController will point to your navigationController.

Comment: that's what I was suspecting, cause I am obtaining another viewController when I try to access the presentingViewController property. But why not simply creating a property on B of type id, to store the caller vc?

Comment: One argument against the property on B is that it would create a very tight coupling between A and B. If you create the property as type id, how would you pass information to A without knowing its class?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it's for single fire use and there is not a lot of collaboration I tend to prefer blocks over delegation as it's seems a bit tidier.

For example if it was just to call back when you have finished using the secondViewController I would:

Add a block property to the SecondViewController

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) void (^onCompletion)(void);
```

Then in the firstViewController when you create the secondViewController

```
- (void)showSecondViewController;
{
  SecondViewController *viewController = [[SecondViewController alloc] init];
  viewController.onCompletion = ^{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
  };

  [self presentViewController:viewController
                 animated:YES
               completion:nil];
}
```

Then in the secondViewController when you are finished

```
- (IBAction)doneTapped;
{
  if (self.onCompletion) {
    self.onCompletion();
  }
}
```

If you need a return value then just modify the block to accept an argument

Comment: wow, your explanation melted my brain... that block property blown me away. Block property? I never realized I could use blocks as properties... Can I do that in iOS >= 4.3 ? I am trying to digest your answer, but as it is coming from a different energy level, it will take a while... 

Comment: where exactly the secondVC gets a reference to the firstVC?

Comment: In the second chunk of code above we are in the firstViewController, which is where we create the block. I would read up on blocks as it sounds like you've not used them before? In the example above I am referring to the firstViewController by the fact that I am calling `dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:` in the block and `self` is referring to the current object, (which is the firstViewController).

Comment: yes, I use blocks, but this block as property stuff sounded exoteric to me.

Comment: what sounded strange to me is that properties declaration generally have the format @property (..., ...) Class propertyName and this block property of yours defies that logic...

Answer (score 2):

If your deployment target is iOS 5 or later, perhaps the [`presentingViewController`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIViewController/presentingViewController) property will give you what you need.

If your deployment target is iOS 4, you might get what you need from the `parentViewController` property.

Otherwise, you need to define your own property.

Comment: Yeah, parentViewController is your friend. Just be careful: the property still exists in iOS5 but has different behavior. See: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: this is strange but if I compile for iOS 6 and use presentingViewController it gives me another viewController that is not the one which presented the controller and if I compile for iOS 5 and use parentViewController it gives me nil...

Comment: That's why I used weasel words like “perhaps” and “might”. :) Sounds like you need to define your own property.

Answer (score 1):

I would advise to use delegation. You declare a property on vcB and set vcA as the delegate. That way you can communicate various state changes to the presenting UIViewController.

First make a protocol declaration and declare a delegate property.

```
// ViewControllerB.h

@class ViewControllerB;

@protocol ViewControllerBDelegate <NSObject>
- (void)viewControllerDidClose:(ViewControllerB *)viewController;
@end

@property (unsafe_unretained, nonatomic) id<ViewControllerBDelegate> delegate;
```

Then call the delegate when a certain event happens. Make sure to check that the receiving object implements the protocol.

```
// ViewControllerB.m

- (IBAction)closeButtonTapped:(id)sender 
{
    if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(viewControllerDidClose:)]) {
        [self.delegate viewControllerDidClose:self];
    }
}
```

Then implement the protocol in vcA.

```
// ViewControllerA.h

@interface ViewControllerA : UIViewController <ViewControllerBDelegate>
```

Set vcA as the delgate of vcB.

```
// ViewControllerA.m

- (void)presentVcB {
    vcB = [[ViewControllerB alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    vcB.delegate = self;
    [self presentModalViewController:vcB animated:YES];
}
```

And respond accordingly when the method is called.

```
// Implementing ViewControllerBDelegate
- viewControllerDidClose:(ViewControllerB *)viewController {
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Note that this pattern can be use for a variety of purposes, not only dismissing the modal view.

Comment: +1 thanks for the effort and for the good solution, but Paul's is simpler for my case.

Comment: His is indeed a clever solution.